# Auto create shipment id as soon as New order arrives in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipment, shipment-tracking

I want to auto create the shipment id for the magento order as soon as the order arrives, the shipment id gets created only when we invoice, so can you please tell me how to do it as soon as order arrives?

Comment: can anyone answer this please

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom extension with the observer of the following events:

```
sales_order_save_after
checkout_submit_all_after
```

Where you can get order increment ID and use Magento API for the creation of shipment:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api_v2')->create($orderIncrementId, array(), '', false, false);
```

You can check params of the create function here, probably it will be useful to use some of these, like sending email or adding of comment:

> Magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api/V2.php

Also, I advise to surround this code by a try block, to facilitate the catching of potential exceptions.
You can stumble upon the pitfalls during getting of an increment id of order if you are using multishipping feature in your Magento.
So you need use code, something like this:

```
$orders = $observer->getOrders(); // multishipping
if (!$orders) {
    $orders = array($observer->getOrder());
}
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
    try {
        Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api_v2')->create($orderIncrementId, array(), '', false, false);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getCustomMessage(), null, 'Auto_Shipment.log', true);
    }
}
```

Please pay attention, I am using the `getCustomMessage` method, because `$e` is an instance of the `Mage_Api_Exception` class and using of the `getMessage` method will cause the Fatal error.